# How to serve PDF from blob file in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

I am trying to create a web app using Google App Engine (Python) that allows users to upload PDFs and view them later.  I have been able to save the PDFs with BlobProperty in the NDB Datastore, but when I pull the files out of the database they are pure text strings with strange characters.

I have tried using the object tag in HTML as well as PDFObject, but both take as input a url for the PDF rather than a blob file.  Is there a way to go straight from my blob file to a PDF? I would be happy to provide a downloadable link if it is too hard to actually display the PDF on the page.

```
class Thing(ndb.Model):
    blob = ndb.BlobProperty()

HTML2 = """\
    <object data={s} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    """

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        thing_query = Thing.query()
        things = thing_query.fetch()

        for thing in things:
            self.response.write(HTML2.format(s=thing.blob))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?  Did you set the Content-Type headers to `'application/pdf'`?

Comment: Uploaded my code!  Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The [blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) is designed for upload and download of binary data. You can use it for PDFs.

Store only the blob key (String) in the datastore. The upload handler will pull your PDF from a file input in a form with enctype="multipart/form-data", upload it to the BlobStore, and allow you to save the blobkey.

You can then serve the PDF from the blobstore using a handler that pulls the blobkey from the relevant model in the datastore.

Here are some example handlers for upload and download.

```
class Thing(ndb.Model):
    blobkey = ndb.StringProperty()

class UploadBarcodeBG(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads()
        if len(upload_files):
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            thing = Thing()
            if thing and blob_info:
                thing.blobkey = str(blob_info.key())
                thing.put()
                self.redirect_to("ServeThing", thingkey=thing.key())


class ServeThing(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, thingkey):
        thing = Thing.get(thingkey)
        if thing and thing.blobkey:
            blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(thing.blobkey)
            self.send_blob(blob_info)
        else:
            self.error(404)
```